# How can I check whether all JavaScript functions have loaded properly on a page?

Tags: javascript

How can I check whether all JavaScript functions have loaded properly on a page?

Comment: @yogi page means js page or in browser?

Comment: yes page means jsp page in broweser. having more than 20 javascirpts functions on page..Wat exactly happens is, not all time but in rare cases last few say 2 to 3 functions does not load on page.. while seeing the viewsource i came to know than function loaded half .. and that functions was placed at the end of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript blocks the browser from continuing to add elements to the DOM render elements on the screen so technically any script tag would have to be evaluated before the end of the closing BODY tag.

The window's load event is fired after DOM is complete and after all assets (CSS, images, SCRIPT) are loaded... but only if they were added to the DOM before the load event fired.  Any timers or asyncronous calls (ajax, iframes, etc) could escape this method.

In a complicated asyncronous environment, you may have AJAX loading content or you may have timers set to lazy-load SCRIPT tags.

There's no single answer to your question, but the window's load event is the most likely answer.

You can always test to see if a function exists before using it

```
function foo(params) { /* do stuff */ }
...
if(foo) { foo(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/1843) and [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) in firefox to check the js files loaded or not and web devloper will show errors if you have any errors in javascript function..

Answer (score 0):

use document onload event

[link text](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0280__Document/documentonload.htm)